# FileUpload control inside update panel in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am developing an application in which is in SharePoint 2010.
I have used file upload control inside update panel, there is also two more  text boxes for name and address. When i click on button i am not getting file name from file upload control. 
Following is my code, please tell me where i am going wrong or whats the reason for not getting file control value after button click.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Image ID="NormalImage" runat="server" />
 </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Upload" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where do you want use update panel? **application page** or **web part**?

Answer (score 0):

can you remove the **triggers** section and try.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div>
<table width="50%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Image ID="NormalImage" runat="server" />
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: In **Application Page** and **WebPart** you can not use your own **ScriptManager**.

Comment: I,m not focusing on script manager, i want rahul to try without the triggers section.

Comment: When you want use another **ScriptManager** control in **Application Page** or **WebPart**, you face an error page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />`

Add `ScriptManager` to Page programmatically:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Init += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e_Init)
                 {`enter code here`
                     if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) == null)
                     {
                         ScriptManager sMgr = new ScriptManager();
                         Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, sMgr);
                     }
                 };
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```